# Node.js Cannot Find Module error on npm start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

I am getting an error like the below when I run `npm start` command to start the server for my first react project. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the node.js but did not work. How can I resolve this issue? I am including my `package.json` and my directory structure over here.

This is the error:

```
    > reactproject1@1.0.0 start C:\Users\LENOVO\reactproject1
    > node index.js
    
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
      throw err;
      ^
    
    Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\LENOVO\reactproject1\index.js'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
        at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
        at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
      code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
      requireStack: []
    }
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! reactproject1@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the reactproject1@1.0.0 start script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-18T09_12_04_972Z-debug.log
```

This is my `package.json` file of my react project. I have edited it by adding `"start":"node index.js"`.

```js
{
  "name": "reactproject1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "restropart",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },

  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  }
}
```

My Directory tree is as follows

```
-ReactProject
  -node_modules
  -public
  -src
    ->index.js
  -package.json
  -package-lock.json
```

My `index.js` file resides inside the `src` folder. The `node_modules`, `public`, `src`, `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files are on the same line.

Comment: Do you have an `index.js` file in the project's root?

Comment: Can you show your project file structure and where is the index.js file located

Comment: I have added my project file structure in the question. Please go through it. @Mureinik . Thank you for responding.

Comment: @ShauryaVardhanSingh I am glad for your response. I have added the structure in my question area. Please help to resolve the error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The start script refers to `index.js`, but you don't have such a file - it's under `src/index.js`. You could either move it to the project root, or update the `start` script accordingly:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js"
},
```